# What could be another way to remove animation from a div instead of transitionend?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a web virtual drumkit that triggers an animation and a sound for each div (or key) touched. Every time the user click or touch one key, the sound restart at 0, this part is fine but I'm struggling with the animation.

After the animation is done for one key, I remove it with a function triggered by the event **transionend**. But the problem is: if the user is touching rapidly one key multiple times in a row, the transitionend doesn't occur (because the animation doesn't end), and then the class 'key-animation' doesn't go off. 
[![drum kit where the animation on the 'S' doesn't go off][2]][2]

````
audio.play();
keysound.classList.add('key-animation');

function removeTransition(e) {
     if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
     this.classList.remove('key-animation');
}

let keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVtxj.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmFzA.png
````

Comment: I recommend reading this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API and see the examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API